# Checking out projects with "forbidden" file names

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, phpstorm

I have need to make changes to a web app that was developed entirely in Linux.  I'm trying to check it out on my Windows machine, in order to use my local IDE (PHPStorm) to edit it.

The problem is that the project contains several files with three-letter base names, like `con` and `nul`.  I'm aware that those file names aren't allowed in Windows, for historical reasons.  However, their existence is causing a regular checkout to break.

I don't need the badly named files, or any of the files in the same directories; they, or the nearest common parent of all that stuff, could be excluded from the checkout, and it wouldn't bother me.  But the checkout stuff in PHPStorm seems not to want to let me exclude just one deeply nested subtree; it either wants to check out the whole thing or only immediate children.

The app has close to 45000 files, and the server hosting the repository is not exactly a speed demon (to put it mildly).  Picking files or directories one by one seems like it will be painfully slow.

How do i convince PHPStorm (or, failing that, TortoiseSVN) to:

- check out everything *but* certain files or subdirectories deep down in the tree, *or*
- skip items it can't store locally, ideally marking them as excluded?

Comment: Is renaming these files an option?

Comment: Not in this version.  There's a newer release that has the files renamed for exactly this reason, but the release i have to fix needs them to stay as they are.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use svn from within cygwin, and then delete the bad filenames once you have them on your machine. Cygwin can handle [special filenames](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html) that won't work otherwise in Windows. Hopefully somebody else will have a better answer!